# Python tkinter buttons from sql query

Tags: python, arrays, tkinter

i'm completely new to python and try to wrap my head about the following problem.
I need to create buttons from an sql query.
Right now one button looks like this (i skip style things)

```
def __init__ (self, screen):

    self.frame = Frame(screen)
    self.frame.grid()            
    self.button01Image = PhotoImage(file=row[2])
    self.button01 = Button(
        self.frame,
        image = self.button01Image,
        command = self.button01Activate,
        )
    self.button01.grid(row = 0, column = 0)


    def button01Activate(self):
        self.button01.configure(
            state = DISABLED
            )
        dosomething(23)
        dosomething(01)
```

result (row) from sql query looks like this

```
('01', '23', 'picturefilename.png' ,'0')
```

In the end i want something like this, yes i know that it doesn't work.

```
def __init__ (self, screen):

    self.frame = Frame(screen)
    self.frame.grid()            
    self.button + row[0] Image = PhotoImage(file=row[2])
    self.button + row[0]  = Button(
        self.frame,
        image = self.button01Image,
        command = self.button01Activate,
        )
    if row[3] == 0
        self.button + row[0] + .configure(
            state = DISABLED
            )
    #counting up to a 3x5 grid)
    self.button + row[0] + .grid(row = 0, column = 0)


    def button + row[0] + Activate(self):
        self.button + row[0] + .configure(
            state = DISABLED
            )
        dosomething(row[1])
        dosomethingelse(row[0])
```

So basically i need to assign functions and pictures to the button from the database.

I got no clue where to start change things here, i guess my approach is completely wrong.
Can somebody point me into the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You have to construct the Activate functions through a closure.

I have replaced the images with text for the example. Just look at the comments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk

class CreateButtons:
    def __init__ (self, screen, sqlresult):

        self.frame = tk.Frame(screen)
        self.frame.grid()
        self.buttons = {}
        for i,row in enumerate(sqlresult):
            #buttonImage = PhotoImage(file=row[2])
            buttonId = row[0]
            button = tk.Button(
              self.frame,
              text = 'button-'+str(buttonId)
              #image = buttonImage
            )
            button['command'] = self.createButtonCommand(buttonId, row[1])
            self.buttons[buttonId] = button
            if row[3] == 0:
                button.configure(state = tk.DISABLED)
            #counting up to a 3x5 grid)
            button.grid(row = i//5, column = i%5)

    def createButtonCommand(self, buttonId, buttonArg):
        def command():
            self.buttonActivate(buttonId, buttonArg)
        return command

    def buttonActivate(self, buttonId, buttonArg):
        button = self.buttons.get(buttonId)
        if not button: return
        button.configure(state = tk.DISABLED)
        print("Button Pressed:", buttonId)
        #dosomething(buttonArg)
        #dosomethingelse(buttonId)


sqlresult = [(0,1,'pict1.png',1),(4,6,'pict2.png',0),(10,11,'pict3.png',1)]
root = tk.Tk()
CreateButtons(root, sqlresult)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: That does exactly what i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: @OkayDokey: Maybe you can mark it as selected Answer.